# CoreData Unexpectedly Found Nil

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to keep my CoreData setup as simple as possible and am using a singleton to manage the instance.  When I attempt to save data, however, either my entity or NSManagedObjectContext are coming up nil.  I've tried different ways of creating the instance with no success.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

```
import CoreData

class SingletonCoreData {

  static let sharedInstance = SingletonCoreData()

  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

  func saveData(name: String) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "People", in: context). //"Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
    let newName = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    let UserDBObj = NSManagedObject()
    context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    newName.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
          print("Storing Data..")
          do {
              try context.save()
          } catch {
              print("Storing data Failed")
          }
      }
```

[image]

EDIT: Updated an attempt

```
func saveData(name: String) {
    context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "People", in: context)
    let newName = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) //nil now found here

    newName.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
          print("Storing Data..")
          do {
              try context.save()
          } catch {
              print("Storing data Failed")
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning to `context` before using it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I updated with another unsuccessful attempt; am I headed in the correct direction?

Comment: It's pretty confusing to see both `Persons` and `People`. Can't diagnose without an accurate name for your entity!

Comment: Aha!  That may have been the issue.  Now I'm getting "CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'People' for entity 'People'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead", however that's a whole different issue I can pursue.  Thanks!